# How to instantiate several controllers of single type in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, routes

I thought I had a common business case but cannot find an appropriate solution for that.

So, suppose I have LoaderController which has a number of database actions like load, save, etc. It loads and saves the objects of a single type (i.e. this is not a generic controller). BUT: it can load objects from different databases - that's the point.
So, if a user calls /db1/load - the system loads data from database db1, /db2/load - from database db2, etc. Also, I have a kind of a shared environment, so I can't be sure that the first segment is always the database name. There might be other cases like /report/id which don't correspond to LoaderController but have to live with that type of route "/x1/x2" as well.

Well, the basic idea is to somehow register all my database endpoints like (pseudocode):
Register("db1", controller = typeof(LoaderController), parameter="ConnectionStringToDb1"), but I cannot understand how to do that. Not only registering that type of route is an issue but also pushing the connection string parameter into the particular controller in any way.

Comment: Hi @ademchenko, what do you mean for `There might be other cases like /report/id which don't correspond to LoaderController but have to live with that type of route "/x1/x2" as well`? If you use web api, just use route attribute and avoiding using conflict route.

Comment: I mean there might be several controllers with route "[controller][action]" and the LoaderContoller with route "[databaseName][action]".

Comment: So what's wrong? What do you want? What does the routing influence?

Comment: The database names are loaded from config and are unknown on the compilation stage